# Talend: tMAP LookUp - fist match after row

Tags: vlookup, talend

Hello I'm facing an issue using tMap component and Vloopup feature.
Basically I got as input an excel file, witch I've duplicate the input, one for main row other for lookup:
[image]

Excel Column (FileInputExcel_1 + FileInputExcel_3):

[image]

My Goal is:
FileInputExcel_1 is iterating row by row,
for EACH FileInputExcel_1 row I need to lookup FileInputExcel_1 COL3 in COL2
RETURN FIRST MATCH FileInputExcel_3 COL1 value
FIRST MATCH FileInputExcel_3 ROW >= actual ROW iteration FileInputExcel_1

ie: ROW 1  result should be 61416:

[image]

ie: ROW 5 result should be 3225:

[image]

I've already tried to play with tMap, but I don't understand how keep the ROW rules: I'm failing always obtaining the first match despite of the cursor (BN_LINE variable is returned only at and of subjob, so cannot use it).
Any idea/workaround?
Thanks a lot

Comment: The cursor of the lookup will always start from top, for every excel row you iterate through in your main loop. I'd be curious if this can be changed. Maybe after every iteration the iterated row must be consumed in all sources, but how to do it, I am not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got another suggestion I've changed a bit, working 100% and using only Talend component without JAVA snippet code.
[image]

1st, add a column (rank for example) representing the row number in the tFileExcelInput; result buffered into tHashOutput_1

[image]

2nd, use the tMap to join tHashOutput_1 with itself, filtering on rank, make sure to select All Matches
[image]

3rd, eliminate duplicates using tUniqRow

Answer (score 2):

In the tMap you have to join (inner join incase you want get the records which have match) the input and lookup as follows.

row3.COL3= row4.COL2

then map  result in the right side of tMap as

row4.COL1 -->result.

Comment: That's exactly what I did, but this does not match my cursor requirements any idea how?

Answer (score 1):

If you aware with Java, you can first load yours Excel File values (col1 and col2) in a Java List (ArrayList).
Then iterate your Excel file, incrementing a counter. For each line, find the first match in the Java List but you begin at the index equals to your counter.

(sorry for my bad english)

**Edit:** Example with TOS 6.2.1
2 context variables:
- myValues (Object)
- index (Integer) default 0

[a busy cat http://img4.hostingpics.net/pics/478043schema.png](http://img4.hostingpics.net/pics/478043schema.png)

First we load your excel datas in the list. we iterate your file, for each row in the tJavaRow component "load datas":

```java
if(context.myValues == null){
  context.myValues = new java.util.ArrayList<>();
}
// Create a pair contening col1 and col3
javafx.util.Pair<String, String> pair = new javafx.util.Pair<>(input_row.col1, input_row.col3);
// Add the pair in the list
((java.util.ArrayList<javafx.util.Pair<String, String>>)context.myValues).add(pair);
```

Then we iterate again excel1 (like in your job), but in the tjavaRow "index", we search the first match since the current index:

```java
java.util.ArrayList<javafx.util.Pair<String, String>> myList = ((java.util.ArrayList<javafx.util.Pair<String, String>>) context.myValues);
// For each row in the list startin from the current index
for(int i = context.index; i < myList.size(); i++){
  javafx.util.Pair<String, String> currentPair = myList.get(i);
  // if col3 == col2
  if(currentPair.getValue().equals(input_row.col2)){
    output_row.expectedCol1 = currentPair.getKey();
    break;
  }
}
// move to next index
context.index++;
```

Hope it will helps you

Comment: Thx, but using witch component?

Comment: tJavaRow, inside you can write Java commands.  Use context variables to store your list.